# Delete Ubuntu file from Windows

Tags: windows

How can I delete one file from Ubuntu using Windows. I installed Ubuntu 10.04 but I have some issues I can't solve without deleting or changing one file, and every time I boot Ubuntu my mouse stops working and my keyboard goes crazy.

Comment: was is installed using wubi?

Comment: no, it's regular installation

Comment: It would be interesting to know what file you want to delete.

Comment: well, deleting was just an option, I needed to change /etc/default(irqbalance file, I needed to disable irqbalance because it made my keyboard and mouse to stop working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install ext2fsd on windows. It will detect your ext3, ext4 drives of Ubuntu.
You can download it from 
[ext2fsd.com](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16)

Comment: it seems that it doesn't recognise ext4. When I try to open partition ti says that volume is not formated

Comment: it's ok, I fixed it. I needed to reboot and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are unable to access your Ubuntu system and need to delete some files to fix the issue?

One approach could be to access the Ubuntu partition from your system. Here are some tools.

**Explore2fs**

[Homepage](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)

[image]

__

**DiskInternals Linux Reader**

[Homepage](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

[image]

---

**Ext2read**

[Homepage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

If you installed Ubuntu using Wubi, you could easily locate the Ubuntu folder from your Windows machine and delete them from there.